# What does a plain yield keyword do in Python?

Tags: python, yield

According to [the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-yield_expression) the yield keyword **can** take an "[expression_list](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-expression_list)", but it is optional:

```
yield_expression ::=  "yield" [expression_list]
```

I can find no examples of such usage, either in the Python docs, in any of the answers to [What does the yield keyword do in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python), nor from generally reading around the web.

If `yield` is used without an `expression_list` then I guess that the resulting method cannot be useful as a generator, so are there other scenarios where a plain `yield` might be useful?

Comment: It can be used in a `with` statement. See the example in [contextlib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Although they're almost always used as simple generators, `yield` enables fully-fledged **[coroutines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21541902/1595865)**.

Besides being used to send values out of a generator / co-routine, `yield`  can also **receive** values, with the effect of coordinating the execution different co-routines. Thus, you don't need `expression_list` if you only want to coordinate or receive values.

Here's a simple example:

```
def infini_printer():
    while True:
        received = yield # get the received value into a variable
        print(received)

printer = infini_printer()
printer.next()              # returns None, since we didn't specify any expression after yield
printer.send("foo")         # prints "foo"
```

Answer (score 4):

It works more like how a `return` with no arguments simply returns `None`.

```
>>> def foobar():
...    for i in range(10):
...        yield
>>>
>>> for token in foobar():
...    print(token)
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
```

Where this is going to be more common is when you are writing coroutines where there is important work you are doing in a function, and the `yield` point is simply the 'pause' point -- waiting for someone or something to call `next` or `send` but you may not have anything of concern to return.

```
>>> def do_important_work():
...
...    do_it = True
...    state = 0
...    while do_it:
...        print(state)
...        state += 1
...        # do some more important work here ...
...        do_it = yield
...
>>> worker = do_important_work()
... 
>>> worker.next()
>>> worker.send(True)
>>> worker.send(True)
>>> worker.send(True)
0
1
2
3
```

I think `yield` was simply designed so you were not *forced* to return a value, just like how `return` is designed.